# How to customize tooltips(text and Format) in Google Vizualization Bar Charts?

Tags: ajax, charts, google-visualization

I am using [Google Visualization Bar Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/barchart.html) and I would like to **customize or change the tooltip text and format** that appears when clicking on a bar.

I have been through documentation but I didn't find a way to implement 
this. Do you know:

1. **Is it even possible**?
2. If so, could you provide some code examples ?

Comment: Please star this issue if you miss this option too: http://goo.gl/17IvM

Comment: Google now supply a way to do this, alot can change in 5 years lol

Answer (score 29):

You can change the way the number is formatted by using the `google.visualization.NumberFormat` class.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 0,
    prefix: '$'
});

formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column.
```

If you need more flexibility, have a look at the `PatternFormat` class.

Here's the [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#numberformatter).

Comment: Who said anything about a number?

Comment: This isn't correct anyway as the OP specified that he wants to change the text in the tooltip. Not just how numbers were formatted on the chart. Why so many upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new data type for what you want in the tool tip:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Game');
data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'}); // here is the tooltip line
```

Now add the info that you want in your tooltip to you data:

```
['$FormatedWeekday', $SalesAll,'$ToolTip']
['$FormatedWeekday', $SalesAll,'$ToolTip']
['$FormatedWeekday', $SalesAll,'$ToolTip']
```

You will loose all the default data in your toll tip so you might want you re-package it:

```
$ToolTip = ''.$FormatedWeekday.' \u000D\u000A '.$SalesAll.' \u000D\u000A '."Red Cross  Event";
```

the "\u000D\u000A" forces a line break

Comment: "\n" also seems to force a line break, I'd like to make part of the text bold too though.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do a similar thing with a Google pie chart. With the original code, on mouseover, the tooltip was showing the label, the raw number, and the percentage.

The orignal code was:

> data.setValue(0, 0, 'Christmas trees');
>
> data.setValue(0, 1, 410000000);

And the tooltip would show "Christmas trees 410000000 4.4%."

To format the text, I added a line to the code, so it was:

> data.setValue(0, 0, 'Christmas trees');
>
> data.setValue(0, 1, 410000000);
>
> data.setFormattedValue(0, 1, "$410 million");

The result was a tooltip that read, "Christmas trees $410 million 4.4%"

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thx Katy. I will give it a try and post my results here

Answer (score 3):

Google Chart not support format html tooltip LineChart, BarChart.
I use:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(rowColumn){
                                myFunction();
                            });
```

in `myFunction()`: you can use `popup` to show more information.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very easy way to do it, you just have to use one of the `Formatters` for the data:

```
// Set chart options
var options = {
hAxis: {format: 'MMM dd, y'}
};

// Format the data
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern:'EEEE, MMMM d, y'});
formatter.format(data,0);

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

You simply format the axis differently from data format, since the data format will only show up when you mouseOver.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are now able to customize tooltip text by adding a special column that has `role: 'tooltip'`: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by adding another column to your data that will act as the tooltip.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number');
    data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});
    data.addRow();
    base = 10;
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Datapoint1');
    data.setValue(0, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(0, 2, " This is my tooltip1 ");

    data.addRow();
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Datapoint2');
    data.setValue(1, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(1, 2, "This is my second tooltip2");

    // Draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, All:

Google added custom HTML/CSS tooltips in September 2012:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same option. Seems like there isn't any direct way. But we can disable the default tooltip and popup our own version using SelectHandler. Do let us know if you have figured out a more better/direct way. Thanks

Comment: that's my exact answer on the mailing list to the same question from the same person :)
Well, I guess I'll just get started...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to disable it was to traverse the DOM in the hover handler (for pie charts anyway):

$(pie.Ac.firstElementChild.contentDocument.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[1].firstChild.childNodes[2]).remove();

Which is hideous and subject to Google maintaining the structure that exists...
is there a better way?

Comment: when you create the chart, you can disable tooltips using the following:


`chart.draw(data, {'tooltip': {trigger: 'none'} });`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DataTable Roles and the tooltip example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles

```
label: 'Year',   'Sales',         null,   'Expenses',         null
`role: domain,     data,       tooltip,         data,      tooltip`
     '2004',       1000,    '1M$ sales,          400,    '$0.4M expenses
                       in 2004'                     in 2004'
     '2005',       1170, '1.17M$ sales,          460,    '$0.46M expenses
                        in 2005'                    in 2005'
     '2006',        660,  '.66M$ sales,         1120,    '$1.12M expenses
                        in 2006'                    in 2006'
     '2007',       1030, '1.03M$ sales,          540,    '$0.54M expenses
                        in 2007'                    in 2007'
```

The **null** labels are used as tooltip for 'Sales' and 'Expenses' respectively.