# Googlechart error on a linechart with tooltip values coming via JSON

Tags: json, google-visualization

I have a google chart and want to add a custom tooltip. I found some great answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068593/how-to-customize-tooltipstext-and-format-in-google-vizualization-bar-charts)  this site and set about doing this with roles. I also found [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles?hl=zh-CN) about it and it looked like the best way.

My data is being generated via json and I use a php file to create a json feed. The rows I have coded like this

```
{"cols": [ {"id":"","label":"Period","pattern":""},
{"id":"","label":"Recorded P/L","type":"number", "role":"data"} ,
{"id":"","label": null,"type":"string", "role":"tooltip"},
{"id":"","label":"Best Available P/L","type":"number", "role":"data"},
{"id":"","label": null,"type":"string", "role":"tooltip"}
    ]
```

Then it goes on and adds all the data. The problem is when I try to run this I get the error

All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

I have checked the json and that is formed correctly but am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your problem is that you're not specifying the type for your first column.